# How do I export calendar?

Tags: views, 8, datetime

I am using the calendar module and I have added many events to it like a timetable.

How can I export these events as an excel format? So that I can see the whole calendar events in the excel file when I need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a view of calendar event data and export data in excel format by the help of [view_data_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)